# Is Peter's original denial of Christ Jesus the only time that Peter denied Jesus?

Tags: john, luke, acts, mark

The New Testament, all of the gospels including other gospels not recorded in the New Testament - are there other denials by Peter?

Comment: I'm fairly new to understanding scripture. I thought that there were other other instances of Peters denial of Christ aside from his original denials before Jesus crucifixion

Comment: Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help (below) as to the purpose and the functioning of this an _hermeneutic_ site. Without an offered text to analyse your question may be closed as we do not debate and discuss biblical topics as such.

Comment: Yes, that is only time when Peter denied christ openly according to four books of gospel

Answer (score 2):

In the New Testament, Peter's denial of Jesus is recorded in all four Gospels: Matthew 26:69-75, Mark 14:66-72, Luke 22:54-62, and John 18:15-27. These passages show the same instance of Peter denying Jesus three times in the courtyard during Jesus' trial and suffering. **There is not another instance in the New Testament where Peter is explicitly described as denying Jesus.**

Matthew 26:69-75
New King James Version

> 69 Now Peter sat outside in the courtyard. And a servant girl came to
> him, saying, “You also were with Jesus of Galilee.”
>
> 70 But **he denied it** before them all, saying, “**I do not know** what you
> are saying.”
>
> 71 And when he had gone out to the gateway, another girl saw him and
> said to those who were there, “This fellow also was with Jesus of
> Nazareth.”
>
> 72 But again **he denied with an oath**, “**I do not know** the Man!”
>
> 73 And a little later those who stood by came up and said to Peter,
> “Surely you also are one of them, for your speech betrays you.”
>
> 74 Then he began to curse and swear, saying, “**I do not know** the
> Man!”
>
> Immediately a rooster crowed. 75 And Peter remembered the word of
> Jesus who had said to him, “Before the rooster crows, **you will deny Me
> three times.**” So he went out and wept bitterly.

Mark 14:66-72
New King James Version

> 66 Now as Peter was below in the courtyard, one of the servant girls
> of the high priest came. 67 And when she saw Peter warming himself,
> she looked at him and said, “You also were with Jesus of Nazareth.”
>
> 68 But **he denied it**, saying, “I neither know nor understand what you
> are saying.” And he went out on the porch, and a rooster crowed.
>
> 69 And the servant girl saw him again, and began to say to those who
> stood by, “This is one of them.” 70 But **he denied it again.**
>
> And a little later those who stood by said to Peter again, “Surely you
> are one of them; for you are a Galilean, and your speech shows
> it.”
>
> 71 Then he began to curse and swear, “**I do not know** this Man of whom
> you speak!”
>
> 72 A second time the rooster crowed. Then Peter called to mind the
> word that Jesus had said to him, “Before the rooster crows twice, **you
> will deny Me three times.**” And when he thought about it, he wept.

Luke 22:54-62
New King James Version

> 54 Having arrested Him, they led Him and brought Him into the high
> priest’s house. But Peter followed at a distance. 55 Now when they had
> kindled a fire in the midst of the courtyard and sat down together,
> Peter sat among them. 56 And a certain servant girl, seeing him as he
> sat by the fire, looked intently at him and said, “This man was also
> with Him.”
>
> 57 But **he denied Him**, saying, “Woman, **I do not know Him.**”
>
> 58 And after a little while another saw him and said, “You also are of
> them.”
>
> But Peter said, “Man, **I am not!**”
>
> 59 Then after about an hour had passed, another confidently affirmed,
> saying, “Surely this fellow also was with Him, for he is a Galilean.”
>
> 60 But Peter said, “Man, **I do not know** what you are saying!”
>
> Immediately, while he was still speaking, the rooster crowed. 61
> And the Lord turned and looked at Peter. Then Peter remembered the
> word of the Lord, how He had said to him, “Before the rooster
> crows, **you will deny Me three times.**” 62 So Peter went out and wept
> bitterly.

John 18:15-27
New King James Version

> 15 And Simon Peter followed Jesus, and so did
> another disciple. Now that disciple was known to the high priest, and
> went with Jesus into the courtyard of the high priest. 16 But Peter
> stood at the door outside. Then the other disciple, who was known to
> the high priest, went out and spoke to her who kept the door, and
> brought Peter in. 17 Then the servant girl who kept the door said to
> Peter, “You are not also one of this Man’s disciples, are you?”
>
> He said, “**I am not.**”
>
> 18 Now the servants and officers who had made a fire of coals stood
> there, for it was cold, and they warmed themselves. And Peter stood
> with them and warmed himself.
>
> 19 The high priest then asked
> Jesus about His disciples and His doctrine.
>
> 20 Jesus answered him, “I spoke openly to the world. I always taught
> in synagogues and in the temple, where the Jews always meet, and in
> secret I have said nothing. 21 Why do you ask Me? Ask those who have
> heard Me what I said to them. Indeed they know what I said.”
>
> 22 And when He had said these things, one of the officers who stood by
> struck Jesus with the palm of his hand, saying, “Do You answer the
> high priest like that?”
>
> 23 Jesus answered him, “If I have spoken evil, bear witness of the
> evil; but if well, why do you strike Me?”
>
> 24 Then Annas sent Him bound to Caiaphas the high priest.
>
> 25 Now Simon Peter stood and warmed himself.
> Therefore they said to him, “You are not also one of His disciples,
> are you?”
>
> **He denied it** and said, “**I am not!**”
>
> 26 One of the servants of the high priest, a relative of him whose ear
> Peter cut off, said, “Did I not see you in the garden with Him?” 27
> **Peter then denied again**; and **immediately a rooster crowed.**

Comment: These references should have been part of the OP's question to make it valid!

Comment: Very full answer, being the only adequate response. Up-voted +1.